# Can I set a variable to a variable combination in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Here's my code:

```
var album1 = "First Album name";
var album2 = "Second Album Name";
var album3 = "Third Album Name";
var album4 = "Fourth Album name";
var album5 = "Fifth Album name";

var currentAlbumCtr = 1;
var currentAlbum = album + currentAlbumCtr;
```

currentAlbum should be set to album1 if currentAlbumCtr is 1.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Have a read here... http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp

Comment: You shall create an array of albums, so that you can get a specific index

Comment: http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html

Comment: This does indeed look like a good use case for an array.

Comment: and most of these: [`[javascript] dynamic variables`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+dynamic+variables).

Comment: @adeneo I think Bergi was right.  It is an XY.  In a real app, there would be a database of albums.  The programmer would query it in code and probably receive back an array of objects. The OP should really be asking "how do I work with album data in a sustainable way?" rather than "how do I access a bunch of globals as if it were an organized array?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `eval` to achieve what you want, but that would probably be the wrong way to do it. Why not use an array:

```
var album = [];
album[1] = "First Album name";
album[2] = "Second Album Name";
album[3] = "Third Album Name";
album[4] = "Fourth Album name";
album[5] = "Fifth Album name";

currentAlbumCtr = 1;
currentAlbum = album[currentAlbumCtr];
```

Or, alternatively,

```
var album = {
    "1": "First Album name";
    "2": "Second Album Name";
    "3": "Third Album Name";
    "4": "Fourth Album name";
    "5": "Fifth Album name";
};
```

Or even

```
var album = [
    "First Album name",
    "Second Album Name",
    "Third Album Name",
    "Fourth Album name",
    "Fifth Album name"
];

currentAlbumCtr = 1;
currentAlbum = album[currentAlbumCtr-1];
```

Note the `-1` on the last statement since arrays are normally indexed from 0

Comment: Your array indices are odd. Why not use an array literal?

Comment: Closest to the OP's original code. There's nothing wrong with skipping an index.

Comment: …apart from that `album.length` is `6`?

Comment: @Bergi Only about half of his array indices are odd. There does seem to be a choice between array index/ description mismatch and proper array length.  Usually the first concern loses because the user doesn't need to see the array indexes.

Comment: @Paul: I didn't mean "odd" as in "not even", but rather "strange". I'm not a native speaker :-/ How would you have phrased that?

Comment: @Bergi Ah well, that word "odd" has both meanings so you did OK.  You could have said "Why are you creating an array-like object with string indices instead of an array?" but what you said was fine.

Comment: Thanks - I feel dumb for not originally thinking to use an array... lazy sunday I guess.

Answer (score 0):

> currentAlbum should be set to album1 if currentAlbumCtr is 1.

```
if (currentAlbumCtr == 1) {
    currentAlbum = album1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're asking for. Does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/DBxj6/1/) work?

**script:**

```
var albums =
           [ "album1",
             "album2",
             "album3" ];

$("#clickme").click(function(){
    var currentAlbum = parseInt($("#album_number").val()) % albums.length;
    alert(albums[currentAlbum]);
})
```

**HTML:**

```
<button id="clickme">click!</button>
<input id="album_number"></input>
```

Comment: @Bergi Well, that was just for grabbing the input value. I wasn't sure bow the OP wanted to set it up.

Answer (score -1):

```
var currentAlbum = eval("album" + currentAlbumCtr);
```

Comment: That's why `eval` is evil.

Comment: eval is not evil in this case, ps: that could do without -1, its a working solution still

Comment: No, this is exactly the case where [`eval` is a bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/87260/1048572), and that's worth a downvote. Especially when introducing this to a learner: At some day he will learn what `eval` is good for, but he will need to understand arrays first.

Comment: `currentAlbumCtr = ';document.write("Minimalism forever.")'`